# Earth gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, weight

[image]

If the gravitational vector field of the earth is something as in the picture above, then the net field would sum up to zero by symmetry, but why don't we experience weightlessness?

Comment: You literally said a field exists and you ask why we don't feel weightlessness. We have mass and there's a field => there's a force acting on us.

Comment: Can you explain "then the net field would sum up to zero by symmetry"?

Comment: Hint: you are not sitting exactly in the middle of the earth.

Comment: "*the net field would sum up to zero by symmetry*" True, but only in one point. In the very centre of the planet, the "arrows" point equally from all directions. They cancel each other out - but only there, in the centre, not anywhere else. Not at the surface, for example. At any other point in your image, the "arrows" do *not* cancel out.

Comment: The picture is not correct. Gravity is closed field lines, not opened field lines.

Comment: It seems like it should be fairly obvious that this applies only to the entire Earth as a whole.  I don't know about you, but I'm only a small person on the Earth, not the Earth itself.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need a calculus - to integrate all gravity forces over infinitesimal masses in a body - to understand this.

## Calculus visually

#### a) Object near surface

[image]

Net gravity force is directed towards the center of mass

#### b) Object closer to center

[image]

Net gravity force is still directed towards the center of mass. However it's magnitude is *smaller* than in (a) case because now you can see that there exists a net force which drags object outwards from the center too.

#### c) Object at the center

[image]

Net gravity force is zero - because individual forces cancels each other out completely.

Answer (score 1):

As per your logic, the gravitational field will sum upto zero only at the center of the Earth (which is the earth's inner core). We are living on the surface of the Earth which is why we are experiencing the force acting on us

Answer (score -1):

Since Earth has finite radius, so on its surface there will be net gravitational field pulling you towards the centre of Earth